# Is there a way to put API gateway in front of AWS Secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, api-gateway, aws-secrets-manager

I am wanting to create an API that goes in front of AWS Secrets manager and use the api to get secret values. In terms of security of accessing the API, I'm not worried about security of the API Gateway since I can set up authorization keys/certificates and the API will only be access by the lambda.

When I attempted to add the secrets manager and test the API, I was met with `<UnknownOperationException/>`

Here is the current setup of my API Gateway

[image: API Gateway configuration for Secrets manager]

Is there any documentation on doing something like this, if it's even possible? All and any help is appreciated.

EDIT: More explanation

I want to know if there is an API Gateway only solution for this
mainly because of package size, execution time, and RAM Usage if I were to have a lambda as a middleman. If I use a lambda function to get the secrets from Secrets manager, the max amount of ram used is the max amount of whatever I set as the lambda function (i.e. Lambda function has 128MB ram or 10GB ram, the lambda function will use up all 1of it to get the secrets).

Comment: You could achieve this with a lambda function. Basically, use the awssdk for your lambda language of choice to access the secrets. EG python uses boto3. Just point the Gateway endpoint to the lambda and implement your secrets logic in there.

Comment: You said "the API will only be access by the lambda". If you're using API Gateway to proxy a Lambda function accessing Secrets Manager then why not just give the Lambda function IAM permissions for the secret in Secrets Manager?

Comment: @jarmod Mainly because of package size, execution time, and RAM Usage. If I use a lambda function to get the secrets from Secrets manager, the max amount of ram used is the max amount of whatever I set as the lambda function (i.e. Lambda function has 128MB ram or 10GB ram, the lambda function will use up all 1of it to get the secrets).

Comment: Wow, interesting. Which programming language and which version of the relevant AWS SDK?

Comment: Node 16 for the lambda, and the AWS SDK Version is 3.223.0